# Pacakge Could Not Parsed. Removing non-system package

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, android-emulator

I am trying from 2 days but cannot understand what is exactly happening.When i tried to install apk via USB it work fine But when Install from Gmail App Showing **Package Could Not Parse**.Please Help I am Stuck.I am using Google Cloud Messaging and jtds JDBC Libraries. Heres my **LOG CAT**

```
06-23 03:10:46.049: D/AndroidRuntime(682): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
<br/>
06-23 03:10:46.049: D/AndroidRuntime(682): CheckJNI is ON<br/>
06-23 03:10:46.401: D/AndroidRuntime(682): --- registering native functions ---<br/>
06-23 03:10:47.959: D/dalvikvm(250): GC_EXPLICIT freed 164 objects / 8184 bytes in 165ms<br/>
06-23 03:10:48.929: D/PackageParser(73): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl12765.tmp<br/>
06-23 03:10:52.439: D/dalvikvm(73): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 15105 objects / 840432 bytes in 416ms<br/>
06-23 03:10:54.299: I/PackageManager(73): Removing non-system package:com.android.msfm<br/>
06-23 03:10:54.299: I/ActivityManager(73): Force stopping package com.android.msfm uid=10040<br/>
06-23 03:10:54.329: I/Process(73): Sending signal. PID: 541 SIG: 9<br/>
06-23 03:10:54.419: I/WindowManager(73): WIN DEATH: Window{451f33e0 com.android.msfm/com.android.msfm.LoginActivity paused=false}<br/>
06-23 03:10:54.509: I/UsageStats(73): Unexpected resume of com.android.launcher while already resumed in com.android.msfm<br/>
06-23 03:10:54.884: W/InputManagerService(73): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 541 uid 10040<br/>
06-23 03:10:56.690: D/PackageManager(73): Scanning package com.android.msfm<br/>
06-23 03:10:56.769: I/PackageManager(73): Package com.android.msfm codePath changed from /data/app/com.android.msfm-2.apk to /data/app/com.android.msfm-1.apk; Retaining data and using new<br/>
06-23 03:10:56.789: I/PackageManager(73): /data/app/com.android.msfm-1.apk changed; unpacking<br/>
06-23 03:10:57.018: D/installd(35): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/com.android.msfm-1.apk' ---<br/>
06-23 03:11:05.680: D/dalvikvm(693): DexOpt: load 1524ms, verify 4671ms, opt 288ms<br/>
06-23 03:11:05.919: D/installd(35): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/com.android.msfm-1.apk' (success) ---<br/>
06-23 03:11:05.933: W/PackageManager(73): Code path for pkg : com.android.msfm changing from /data/app/com.android.msfm-2.apk to /data/app/com.android.msfm-1.apk<br/>
06-23 03:11:05.933: W/PackageManager(73): Resource path for pkg : com.android.msfm changing from /data/app/com.android.msfm-2.apk to /data/app/com.android.msfm-1.apk<br/>
06-23 03:11:05.940: D/PackageManager(73):   Services: com.android.msfm.GCMIntentService<br/>
06-23 03:11:05.940: D/PackageManager(73):   Receivers: com.android.msfm.AlarmReceiver com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver<br/>
06-23 03:11:05.940: D/PackageManager(73):   Activities: com.android.msfm.SplashActivity com.android.msfm.LoginActivity com.android.msfm.DashBoard com.android.msfm.RetailerList com.android.msfm.SelectRetailer com.android.msfm.AddNewRetailer com.android.msfm.RetailerDetails com.android.msfm.CustomDialogBox com.android.msfm.TakeOrderStock com.android.msfm.TakeStockOrder com.android.msfm.Order com.android.msfm.TakeOrder com.android.msfm.TodaysMap com.android.msfm.ShopSelection com.android.msfm.ArrangeShop com.android.msfm.MapRoute com.android.msfm.SelectRoute com.android.msfm.NotificationDetails com.android.msfm.Notifications com.android.msfm.PendingOrders com.android.msfm.DisplayRetailers com.android.msfm.SelectTempRetailers com.android.msfm.SelectPendingRejectRetailer com.android.msfm.DisplayRoutes com.android.msfm.SelectPendingRejectRoute com.android.msfm.SelectTempRoutes com.android.msfm.SyncPopUpMenu com.android.msfm.OrderView com.android.msfm.DisplaySo com.android.msfm.TempItemDeleteDialog com.android.msfm.ProductDetails<br/><br/>
06-23 03:11:05.940: D/PackageManager(73):   Permissions: com.android.msfm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE<br/><br/>
06-23 03:11:05.971: I/ActivityManager(73): Force stopping package com.android.msfm uid=10040<br/>
06-23 03:11:06.309: I/installd(35): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.android.msfm-1.apk@classes.dex -> /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.android.msfm-1.apk@classes.dex<br/>
06-23 03:11:06.320: D/PackageManager(73): New package installed in /data/app/com.android.msfm-1.apk <br/>
06-23 03:11:06.349: W/PackageManager(73): Unknown permission android.permission.ADD_SYSTEM_SERVICE in package com.android.phone<br/>
06-23 03:11:06.360: W/PackageManager(73): Not granting permission android.permission.SEND_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED_INTENTS to package com.android.browser (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x1be45) <br/>
06-23 03:11:06.360: W/PackageManager(73): Unknown permission com.google.android.gm.permission.WRITE_GMAIL in package com.android.settings <br/>
06-23 03:11:06.370: W/PackageManager(73): Unknown permission com.google.android.gm.permission.READ_GMAIL in package com.android.settings <br/>
06-23 03:11:06.409: W/PackageManager(73): Unknown permission com.android.providers.im.permission.READ_ONLY in package com.google.android.apps.maps <br/>
06-23 03:11:06.409: W/PackageManager(73): Unknown permission com.google.android.pushmessaging.permission.RECEIVE in package com.google.android.apps.maps <br/>
06-23 03:11:06.820: I/ActivityManager(73): Force stopping package com.android.msfm uid=10040 <br/>
06-23 03:11:07.170: D/dalvikvm(73): GC_EXPLICIT freed 15893 objects / 819592 bytes in 307ms <br/>
06-23 03:11:08.330: D/dalvikvm(207): GC_EXPLICIT freed 70 objects / 3792 bytes in 805ms <br/>
06-23 03:11:16.913: W/RecognitionManagerService(73): no available voice recognition services found <br/>
06-23 03:11:18.196: D/dalvikvm(73): GC_EXPLICIT freed 9699 objects / 508136 bytes in 766ms <br/>
06-23 03:11:26.265: I/installd(35): unlink /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.android.msfm-2.apk@classes.dex <br/>
06-23 03:11:26.339: D/AndroidRuntime(682): Shutting down VM <br/>
06-23 03:11:26.389: D/jdwp(682): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select <br/>
06-23 03:11:26.389: D/dalvikvm(682): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries <br/>
06-23 03:11:27.490: D/AndroidRuntime(711): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<  <br/><br/>
06-23 03:11:27.490: D/AndroidRuntime(711): CheckJNI is ON<br/><br/>
06-23 03:11:27.904: D/AndroidRuntime(711): --- registering native functions ---<br/>
06-23 03:11:29.205: I/ActivityManager(73): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.msfm/.SplashActivity }<br/>
06-23 03:11:29.559: D/AndroidRuntime(711): Shutting down VM<br/>
06-23 03:11:29.580: D/dalvikvm(711): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries<br/>
06-23 03:11:29.609: I/AndroidRuntime(711): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed<br/>
06-23 03:11:30.809: I/ActivityManager(73): Start proc com.android.msfm for activity com.android.msfm/.SplashActivity: pid=720 uid=10040 gids={3003}<br/>
06-23 03:11:35.029: I/ActivityManager(73): Displayed activity com.android.msfm/.SplashActivity: 5117 ms (total 5117 ms)<br/>
06-23 03:11:36.899: I/ActivityManager(73): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.android.msfm/.LoginActivity }<br/>
06-23 03:11:37.721: D/dalvikvm(720): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1222 objects / 83808 bytes in 128ms<br/>
06-23 03:11:42.011: W/ResourceType(73): Skipping entry 0x7f040000 in package table 0 because it is not complex!<br/>
06-23 03:11:42.051: W/ResourceType(73): Skipping entry 0x7f040001 in package table 0 because it is not complex!<br/>
06-23 03:11:45.419: I/ActivityManager(73): Displayed activity com.android.msfm/.LoginActivity: 8419 ms (total 8419 ms)<br/>
06-23 03:11:46.784: D/dalvikvm(320): GC_EXPLICIT freed 102 objects / 6424 bytes in 20531ms<br/>
06-23 03:11:48.071: D/dalvikvm(193): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1786 objects / 91120 bytes in 12179ms<br/>
06-23 03:11:51.613: D/dalvikvm(353): GC_EXPLICIT freed 63 objects / 2960 bytes in 905ms<br/>
06-23 03:11:55.869: D/dalvikvm(207): GC_EXPLICIT freed 690 objects / 38960 bytes in 169ms<br/>
```

Comment: did you sign your apk?

Comment: It Works Fine Before.Yes signed with debug.keystore Is there Problem I think i sign with Another keystore before.

Comment: I think you cannot install APKs with debug.keystore if you're not in usb-debugging-mode.

Comment: Should i sign my apk with new Key.Thank you For Your Time

Comment: If you only used the debugkey before, yes.